# Javascript knockout how to add afterRender

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How can i add afterRender to these two things and call it back in javascipt code:

```
<!-- ko foreach: columns -->
        <th data-bind="atrr: {'class': 'queue-row-' + $data}">
          <!-- ko if: $parent.isSortableColumn($data) -->
            <i class="fa fa-sort"
               data-bind="click: function() { $parent.toggleSortBy($data) }"></i>
          <!-- /ko -->

<tr data-bind="css: {
                       selectedFile: selected,
                       activeFile: $parent.activeQueueFile() == $data,
                    }, attr: {'data-queue-file' : $data.id() }">
```

Added to makeTreeTable to foreach. It's not doing anything:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: {
                        data: visibleQueueFiles,
                        beforeRemove: hideQueueFileElement,
                        afterAdd: showQueueFileElement, 
                        afterRender: showAfterRender,
                        makeTreeTable: itemsThatTriggerUpdate
                      }">
      <tr data-bind="css: {
                       selectedFile: selected,
                       activeFile: $parent.activeQueueFile() == $data,
                    }, attr: {'data-queue-file' : $data.id() }">



        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"
                  data-bind="click: editFile">
            Edit
          </button>


          <a data-bind="click: function() { showInViewer() }"
             class="btn btn-default btn-xs">View</a>

          <span
                data-bind="text: filename,
                           style: {
                           'display' : 'inline-block',
                           'text-decoration': moved() ? 'line-through' : ''
                           }
                           ">

          </span>


          <span data-bind="if: moved">
            Moved to <span data-bind="text: moved_to_qid"></span>
          </span>

          <span data-bind="if: owner">
            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
          </span>

          <span data-bind="if: isNew">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"
               title="File added to queue"></i>
          </span>


        </td>

        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.columns -->
        <td class="qid"
            data-bind="text: $parent.displayForColumn($data),
                       attr: { 'title' : $parent.titleForColumn($data) }">
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->


      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
```

Added this to the Javascript file. It's not returning anything to the console:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.makeTreeTable = {

          update: function(element, valueAccessor) {

                 console.log('1');

                 ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

                 console.log('2');

                 treeTable(element.parentNode());

                 console.log('3');

         }


         };

           this.itemsThatTriggerUpdate = ko.pureComputed(function(){

             console.log('4');

            ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.items, function(item) {

            console.log('5');

            item.id();

            console.log('6');

           });

         return{};

         }, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need, to run code after a `foreach` binding was complete. Here's what I did:

```
<tbody id="datasetbody" data-bind="foreach: items, makeTreeTable: itemsThatTriggerUpdate">
    <!-- content -->
</tbody>
```

Binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.makeTreeTable = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());     // just need a subscription
        treeTable(element.parentNode /* the table element */);
    }
};
```

Computed:

```
this.itemsThatTriggerUpdate = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.items(), function(item) {
        //unwrap properties that cause an update
        item.id(), /*...*/;
    });
    return {};
}, this);
```

Comment: Hey i already added afterRender to the foreach but that's still not helping with aligning my table header. I am not sure how i can turn the css and attr to have the after render. I also posted another article that i didn't get a answer to. It has all the information you might find helpful for giving me a solid answer. Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058625/html-table-header-is-aligning-properly

Comment: It seems you need more than one dependency for the custom binding. That's where a computed observable comes in handy. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Michael look at the code above. I added what you asked, but when ever the view of the table changes and more columns gets added it's not writing anything on the console. which makes me think the code is not working properly. What did i do wrong?

Comment: In the computed, you need to be accessing `visibleQueueFiles` since that's where the data is.

Comment: how do i do that in the javascript file.

Comment: Obviously I don't know your whole viewmodel, but probably `ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.visibleQueueFiles(), ...`

Comment: Changed it to `this.itemsThatTriggerUpdate = ko.pureComputed(function(){

             console.log('4');

            ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.visibleQueueFiles(), function(item) {
 
            console.log('5');

            item.id();
            
            console.log('6');

           });

         return{};

         }, this);` still didn't work

Comment: Didn't see any in the console. Thats why i try to write things to the console by saying console.log and that didn't work.

Comment: Your binding is wrong. You have `makeTreeTable` as an option to `foreach`, but it should be a separate binding: `<tbody data-bind="foreach: { ...  }, makeTreeTable: itemsThatTriggerUpdate">`

Comment: so that kinda works now it writes 1 to the console when i reload my browser also there is an error saying: ReferenceError: "itemThatTriggerUpdate is not defined". Also when the table gets updated i am not seeing anything being written in the console. which makes me think it doesn't think the table is being updated.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "makeTreeTable: function (){return itemThatTriggerUpdate }"
Message: itemThatTriggerUpdate is not defined

Comment: `itemsThatTriggerUpdate` needs to be defined in your viewmodel, the same place where you have `visibleQueueFiles` defined.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that. I am really new to this. Here is the visibleQueueFiles: `var foundActiveFile = false;
            $.each(self.visibleQueueFiles(), function(i, queueFile) {
                if (foundActiveFile) {
                    self.activate(queueFile);
                    foundActiveFile = false;
                    if (deselect) {
                        activeFile.selected(false);
                    }
                }
                if (queueFile === activeFile) {
                    foundActiveFile = true;
                }
            });

        };`

Comment: okay, so i finally got it work but there is still a problem. The update function gets rendered before the whole table column settles down. last thing it writes to the console is 2 even though the table column is still updating and getting bigger. What can i do in this situation?

Comment: Since I don't know why your table hasn't "settled", I can't help much there.

Comment: Is there way to see when knockout settles the table? also I was able to get it to work by setting the css to: `td {
    max-width:1px;    
}
td.qid {   
    max-width:1px;    
}` but it truncates some of the text. Do you have a better way to get this done through css? maybe some way to tell javascript to let us know when the table completely stop building.